# How to include Sqlite database in Android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to include a fairly large Sqlite database in my Android app.  I have tried to follow the reigndesign.com tutorial, but some devices are unable to load the database.  I get exceptions with `dbopen()` calls failing a lot.  It doesn't happen in the emulator or any devices I own, so it is not easy for me to track down.  Is there a proper way to do this that will work on every Android device without fail, or at least for the popular ones?

Is copying the db from the apk to storage still the way to access databases that are included in the apk?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for Android Studio for a simple way to achieve this - [Android SQLite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).